# Блокам устанавливается атрибут style

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

У меня есть блоки фиксированной ширины и высоты. Если их сделать слайдерами с помощью плагина owl-carousel-2, каждому блоку устанавливается атрибут `style=""`, и в нем значение отличается от моего, фиксированного. Из-за этого вид уже не тот.

Как сделать, чтобы атрибут `style` не добавлялся к моим блокам?

Мой код:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    margin: 0,
    nav: false,
    margin: 0,
    dots: false,
    items: 4
});
```

Comment: Было бы проще вам помочь, если бы был ваш пример воспроизводимым. Предположу, что можете перекрыть своими стилями с флагом !important. Либо добавить карусели параметр autoWidth.

Comment: Вы же подключаете к этому блоку owl-карусель, которая приписывает к анимируемым блокам свои стили. Что вам не нравится?